# Trying to manipulate CSS style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation bar at the side of a page and want to highlight one of several entries depending on GET-parameters.

After a little Reading I came to this solution, but it does not seem to work:

in the .html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(highlight_me());
</script>
```

the JS functions:

```
function highlight_me() {
    // ensure all links have class 'regular'
    document.links.className = 'regular';
    // determine which link to highlight
    var id = 'home';
        switch (querystring('view')) {
            case "set":
                id = 'settings';
                break;
            case "mc":
                id = 'messages';
                break;
            default:
                id = 'home';
        }
    // highlight link
    document.getElementById(id).className = 'highlight';
}

function querystring(key) {
    // extract GET-value for key
    var re = new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)' + key + '=(.*?)(?=&|$)', 'gi');
    var r = [], m;
    while ((m = re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r[r.length] = m[1];
    return r;
}
```

the CSS classes:

```
a, a.regular, a:visited {
    color: #f0ce96;
}

a:active, a:hover, a.highlight {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #ffeebb;
}
```

I'd be thankful for a hint that points me to where I go wrong, here.

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the "id" parameter when you call the highlight_me function.

Comment: the id parameter is optional - if none or other than the specified ones are given, id defaults to 'home'

Comment: the JS seems to be right, I don't know much about regular expressions but did you debug the querystring function to check if it is doing what you want?

Comment: Ah... could have thought of that myself. This is, where the problem seems to be - i just copy-pasted that function from somewehere, because someone stated that it worked, so I actually have no real idea, what this piece of code finally does...

Comment: check this http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html it seems to work for me.

Comment: With that, I seem to get no result at all from the query string function. I inserted a simple `alert(results)` and also tried with `alert(results[1])` before the if-clause, but never got anything back other than `null`.

Comment: You only have to pass the name of the URL parameter that you want to get the value. 

Example:

switch (gup('view')) { ...

Comment: Yes, I exchanged the content of `querytring()` and renamed the parameter to `name` to keep changes small

Comment: Ohhhh also check for the switch bracer to be closed, as you can see in the code you posted in the highlight_me function the switch is only opened with { but not closed with } after id="home";

Comment: Oh true, but that was just an error in the paste, the real code has the closing brace (or else my IDE would have also told me ;))

Comment: Which event are you using in the form to get the result of the gup function? onSumbit?

Comment: It is called from highlight_me(), as soon as the document is loaded, so $(document).ready()` is the event, I guess

Comment: That's why it returns nothing, you have to send the form first.

Comment: But there is no form to be sent at this point. I just have a URL like `http://localhost/fdl/index.php?view=mc` and want to switch css classes according to whatever is specified for 'view' (if anything)

Comment: Look at this little one I made http://pastebin.com/G4pFpEwp type something inside the text input, send the form and then press the OK? button.

Comment: Well, I could also do this with PHP, I guess, but I hoped, the JS solution would be smaller/easier...

Comment: Hm, I think I get what you mean, but this will not do what I intended to do... I thought or rather hoped, there was a reasonable way to access the GET parameters just from the URL, without dealing with forms etc.

Comment: Well if you could send me the complete file I could solve it and explain it to you if you want. If it contains any passwords or something just delete them. Anyway I hope I helped to get a more straight way to get the expected result. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you need `id` as a parameter? You're not using it anywhere inside the function. Shouldn't a call to `querystring` be enough?
In that case, you don't need to do the `if(id.length)` part. Set `id` to `'home'` by default, and then have the switch statement to modify the variable accordingly.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
function highlight_me() {
// ensure all links have class 'regular'
document.links.className = 'regular';
// Set id to home by default
var id = 'home';
    switch (querystring('view')) {
        case "set":
            id = 'settings';
            break;
        case "mc":
            id = 'messages';
            break;
        default:
            id = 'home';
    }
// highlight link
document.getElementById(id).className = 'highlight';
}
```

Comment: Good point for simplyfying the function, but I planned on... yeah, what was I actually planning on in the first case? ;)
But unfortunately, the real problem has been already tracked down to the querystring function not working properly, so this does not help to selve this :/

Answer (score 0):

function `$(highlight_me());` want a parameter `id` which is not supply when you call this function.And put your function inside `document.ready`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your function here.
 });
```

Comment: As i stated in answer to Papaya's suggestion, the parameter `id` is optional an defaults to 'home' if not specified or other than defined values (at least my IDE also says so).
But putting it this way: `$(document).ready(highlight_me)` at least made the 'home' part work